# pygraphviz: How to get same edges connected on different ports without iterating?

Tags: python, graph, pygraphviz

I generate the following graph using pygraphviz:

```
graph "Multiport-Switches" {
    node [color="#dddddd",
            label="\N",
            shape=record,
            style=filled
    ];
    Switch0  [label="<1> 1|<2> 2|<3> 3|<4> 4|<5> 5|<6> 6|<7> 7|<8> 8"];
    Switch1  [label="<1> 1|<2> 2|<3> 3|<4> 4|<5> 5|<6> 6|<7> 7|<8> 8"];
    Switch0:1 -- Switch1:1;
    Switch0:2 -- Switch1:2;
    Switch0:3 -- Switch1:3;
    Switch0:4 -- Switch1:4;
    Switch0:5 -- Switch1:5;
    Switch0:6 -- Switch1:6;
    Switch0:7 -- Switch1:7;
    Switch0:8 -- Switch1:8;
}
```

If I iterate through the edges, I can see all of them with the following code:

```
for edge in G.edges():
    print edge, edge.attr
```

The edge tuples are the "same" as you can see by the output below, but they are still differentiated by the attributes. If I want to choose a specific one, I can compare the specific attributes that are different for each of the edges while iterating.

```
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'1', u'headport': u'1'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'2', u'headport': u'2'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'3', u'headport': u'3'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'4', u'headport': u'4'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'5', u'headport': u'5'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'6', u'headport': u'6'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'7', u'headport': u'7'}
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'8', u'headport': u'8'}
```

Now if I use the following code in order to get one edge:

```
edge = G.get_edge('Switch0', 'Switch1')
print edge, edge.attr
```

I only get the last `('Switch0', 'Switch1')` edge as shown below:

```
(u'Switch0', u'Switch1') {u'tailport': u'8', u'headport': u'8'}
```

Is there any way to get a specific, other than the last `(u'Switch0', u'Switch1')` edge without iterating through all of the edges? By passing additional attribute parameters in a method like `get_edge` or similar maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that looks like it's the suggested one according to the documentation [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/reference/agraph.html): `The optional key argument allows assignment of a key to the edge. This is especially useful to distinguish between parallel edges in multi-edge graphs (strict=False).`

When creating the edges, the `add_edge` method has an optional `Key` parameter which is set to `None` by default. If provided with a unique key, then this `Key` can be used when using `get_edge` to retrieve an edge. So if I create the edges with a code like this:

```
# The for-loop will run from 1-8
for port in range(1, 9):
    G.add_edge('Switch0', 'Switch1', key="{}-{}".format(port, port), headport = port, tailport = port)
```

Then I can retrieve specific edges by passing the key that I generated in a unique way earlier:

```
for port in range(1, 9):
    edge = G.get_edge('Switch0', 'Switch1', key="{}-{}".format(port, port))
    print edge, edge.attr
```